# There are 19 residence halls and there are 41 students enrolled in this college. What's the probability that three students live in the same dorm?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There are 19 residence halls and there are 41 students enrolled in this college. What's the probability that three students live in the same dorm? Assuming all students dorm that is.

Just started lesson on probability in Discrete Math. First, I find the size of the sample space. In this case, I believe the sample space is the total number of three-tuples from 41 students, so its 41 C 3.

Finding the probability of the event is difficult. This problem is very similar to the birthday paradox (aka probability of two people having the same birthday in a group of N). Following the birthday paradox's footsteps, first I find the chance that a group of 3 does **not** live in the same dorm. I think this is `p(n) = 1 - 1/19 ∗ 1/18 = 341/342`. Then, I would do $(\frac{341}{342})^{\binom{41}{3}}$, which gets me a totally weird answer (it was a decimal to the -14th power). I would appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Wait a minute, isn't this 100% because of the pidgeonhole principle

Comment: Well.  Are we to assume that each student is assigned a residence hall uniformly at random?  (the way birthdays work, say).

Comment: @lulu Although it did not say on the actual homework, I do believe that it is assumed. For the most part, the rest of the questions also left out that kind of info

Comment: @sgruggy The probability that there is a dorm with at least three students is $1$, yes. However, the question is asking how to find, if given three specific students, the probability that they will be in the same dorm room.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Oh I see. That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: How is my reasoning for the value of p(n)? I tried my best to model it after the birthday paradox.

Comment: @sgruggy This isn't really the birthday paradox, so you shouldn't approach it like that.

Comment: The question really needs to be clarified. Is it about the existence of some set of three students, or about a predetermined set of three students? And any time we discuss probability—and *especially* in a class where it is being introduced to non-experts—the probability distribution *always* needs to be specified. If each student is assigned independently to a residence hall chosen uniformly at random (and we're talking about three predetermined students), then the answer is $1/19^2$. But these clarifications are not optional.

Comment: If we were to interpret this along the lines of the birthday problem, then the answer is extremely close to $1$.  That is, it is nearly certain that there is at least one dorm containing at least three students.

Comment: @lulu It is certain that at least one dorm contains at least three students because if they all contained at most two students, then they would only house $38$ students, which is less than the required $41$.

Comment: @GregMartin I agree with you 100% that this question needs a lot more clarification. I wish I could provide some, but this was the question in its entirety.

Comment: @NobleMushtak  Good point.  Pays to actually look at the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the three students in question are A, B, and C. Without loss of generality, let's call the dorm A is in Dorm 1. Now, assuming that each student is assigned a residence hall uniformly, at random, so that each residence hall is equally likely, the probability that B is in Dorm 1 is $\frac{1}{19}$. Similarly, the probability that C is in Dorm 1 is $\frac{1}{19}$. Thus, we have that the probability that B and C are both in Dorm 1 (and thus the probability that A, B, and C are in the same dorm) is:
$$\frac{1}{19}\cdot \frac{1}{19}=\frac{1}{361}$$

However, this calculation depends on the assumption that each residence hall is equally likely and this assumption should definitely be questioned because it allows for some absurd possibilities, such as all 41 students living in one residence hall and all the others being empty. However, if they really are assigned uniformly at random, then the above is what we find.

Comment: I think a 41:19 student-to-dorm ratio is absurd no matter how it's divided :)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think this is just a really bad problem, though. It is very unclear what my professor was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pigeon-hole principle.

Consider the first 38 students.
Since there are 19 rooms,
the only way that
no room has 3 students
is if all the rooms have
2 students.

Then the next student
will be in a room
with 3 students.

Therefore
the probability is 1
(i.e., certainty).